# Parental permission message when opening Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm revisiting a skill I started making a little while ago, and now it's giving me an odd message when I try to open it.

"To use Alexa Adventure Game skill, a parent needs to give permission. To do that, I sent some information to the home screen of your Alexa App."

I assume the problem has something to do with parental permissions and I want to fix it. This skill worked the last time I used it.

Answer (score 0):

This is something which will come up when you've ticked YES to the question "Is this skill directed to or does it target children under the age of 13?" on the Privacy & Compliance page under Distribution. As a result of this, your skill will be considered a "kid skill".

You only have to enable the use of Alexa kid skills on your account once, but [the process](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/kids) will differ depending on if you are in the US or elsewhere.

If possible, the most straightforward thing would be to open the Alexa App (or the [Alexa website](https://alexa.amazon.co.uk)) and follow the steps to enable kid skills. If you haven't configured your skill to display a card, Amazon suggest you can also go directly to their [parental consent page](https://www.amazon.com/myh/vpc/intro?clientId=Alexa_rw_vpc) to grant the appropriate permissions.

Lastly, one reason why this didn't show up last time you were working on your skill could be that Amazon changed there policy a few months back to now require specific enabling of kid skills.